# How can i be able to apply style on template literals

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, template-literals

I am using template literals to show my data in react, but I want to style that email, how can I be able to apply inline style on that template literal, is there any possibility to do it?
`` {`${eachCustomer?.name} <${eachCustomer?.email}>`} ``

Comment: Needs to be put into another element such as `<span>` that you style

Comment: Hello, actullay i am using material ui and this is my code 

``<TreeItem nodeId={eachCustomer?._id} label={`${eachCustomer?.name} <${eachCustomer?.email}>`} >``

and I want to display a label like that abc-user <abc@abc.com>

Answer (score 1):

Template literals output strings. Styles apply to elements. The idea of applying style to a template literal doesn't make sense.

If you want to apply styles, then create elements. Use JSX. e.g.

```
return <>
    {eachCustomer?.name} &lt;<StyledEmailComponent>{eachCustomer?.email}</StyledEmailComponent>&gt;
</>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{`${eachCustomer?.name} ${eachCustomer?.email ? <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{eachCustomer.email}</span> : null}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to leave this answer here for those looking to style dynamic strings made using template literals. It's possible to use a tag function and assign a css class ***only*** to the variables in the template string, thus styling dynamic values only.

```
export const highlight = (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: (string | number)[]) => {
  let str = '';
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
    str += `${string} <span class='hl'>${values[i] || ''}</span>`;
  });
  return str;
};
```

You can then use it like this in React:

```
  <p
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: highlight`User ${userAddress} claimed ${tokenAmount} ${token.symbol}.`
     }}
  />
```

[This article](https://wesbos.com/tagged-template-literals) by Wes Bos helped me solve that.